# Assigning weights to identify pages

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, machine-learning, web-scraping

I am trying to identify pages which have a list of faculty from a bunch of University Url's.

I have analysed the list of Faculty pages and each page has list of Keywords that occur in them that differentiate them from the other URL's (like designation, phone number, etc). I have made a list of all such Keywords from all the Faculty list pages.

To assign weights to the faculty list pages, I am using the following logic :

I have created a Keyword generator program in python, which takes the URL of the page, calculates the number of occurrences of each word in the page and stores it in a python dictionary in the form name_of_keyword : number_of_occurances (key:value).

1. I input a list of *n* faculty list URL's into my program.
2. Then, each URL is sent to the Keyword generator program, that returns the number of occurrences of each word in that URL.
3. There is a python dictionary in the main program, where the number of occurrences of each keyword (returned from the keyword generator) is added to the corresponding keywords in the main dictionary. (The Keywords in the main dictionary are the one's I found from analyzing the faculty list pages).
4. After going through all the URL's, (after finishing the loop), I divide the value of each keyword in the main dictionary by N (Number of faculty list URL's).
5. The value of each keyword in the main dictionary is the final weights for each Keyword.

To identify the faculty list page from the other pages, I am using the following logic:

1. Send the URL to the keyword generator program, to get the number of occurrences of each keyword in that URL (let us call this URL dictionary).
2. Multiply each keyword of the URL dictionary with the corresponding keyword in the main dictionary found in the previous method(which contains the weights of each keyword. If there is any keyword in the URL dictionary that does not exist in the main dictionary, multiply it by 0).
3. Add the values of all the keywords, that have been obtained after multiplying (step 2).
4. If the sum exceeds a certain threshold (determined manually by experiments and hit and trial), then it is a faculty page.

Even though I am getting an output using this method, it has the following limitations:

- I am using brute force in determining the weights. It is more manual, instead of learning on it's own.
- There is a lot of hit and trial, and experimentation in finding the minimum threshold.
- The solution is not optimal, and the weights cannot be changed by just inputting new Faculty pages. The entire program has to be run again.

I have the following questions :

- What all changes can I incorporate in my current method?
- Is there a more optimal way of assigning weights?
- Is there any learning algorithm that can be used to make the weights assignment more automatic?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are searching for one answer, when another one will suffice.  On one hand, you are trying to compute weights for each page to represent the confidence that the page is a faculty page, but on the other hand you are looking for a simple binary true/false answer:

> I am trying to identify pages which have a list of faculty from a
>   bunch of University Url's.

So to simplify the problem, I would remove the part about computing weights and sums, and instead come up with an algorithm that returns a true/false response about whether a given page is a faculty page.

This could be as simple as scanning for three items: names, email addresses and phone numbers.  If a page has more than one set of these items, it is a list of faculty members.  Maybe not a long list, but a list nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem is, that all faculty list pages do not have the same set of keywords. Some Universities have the email id in the faculty list page while others have it mentioned in the information of the faculty member(ie, some other page). In other words, each faculty list page has a few keywords that distinguish it, that may or may not overlap with the other faculty list pages. Hence, I felt, that computing weights might be a way to solve this problem.

Comment: You are essentially computing weights in your algorithm, to determine if a given page is a faculty list.   One set of weights may be correct for one page, but incorrect for another page.  Because the pages have so much variance, I would instead create an if/elif/elif/else chain to detect the different kinds of pages.

Comment: I would like to make a generalized algorithm, so that it can recognize any page. Creating an if/elif/else chain would only limit the pages recognized to the faculty pages that I manually analyse. Is their any other method possible?

Comment: You're asking an open-ended question.  Please ask a more focused question that can be answered in a few paragraphs.